# How to use "localForage" in Typescript project?

Tags: typescript, webstorm, typescript-typings, localforage

I have a project in Typescript and I want to use the dependency "localForage": https://github.com/localForage/localForage.

I installed it by the following npm command:

> `npm install @types/localforage --save`

I used:

```
 import * as localForage from "localforage";
```

and I get the error:

> error TS1148: Cannot compile modules unless the '--module' flag is
> provided I was looking for solutions and I found TypeScript 0.9.*
> VisualStudio TS5037: Cannot compile external modules unless the
> '--module' flag is provided.

It wasn't relevant for me because I use Webstorm 10.0.5

Comment: You need to actually install the module - `npm i localforage` - the @types package is just typescript definitions

Comment: I tried it. Didn't help

Comment: I opened a new question. This one can be deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What option is chosen in `Settings | Languages & Frameworks | TypeScript` - `Set options manually` or `Use tsconfig.json`? In the former case, make sure to specify `--module commonjs` as **Command line options** value. Otherwise, add `"module": "commonjs"` to your `tsconfig.json`.

Note that you are using very old webStorm version, its TypeScript integration is not up-to-date, you might face issues using the recent TypeScript versions.

Comment: sorry, but this is not the right way to. You posted the question, got the answer; then changed the question to the other one. Now, the accepted answer has nothing to do with the question. Do you expect me to delete my answer and post a new one instead? and, then, you will change your question once more, etc, etc. Once the question is answered, post a new question if you have any

Comment: You're right. I changed it back to the original post you answered.